# Changing JSON values with fetch

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

Hey guys I'm writing a small email app and I am trying to create an archive button for each email. I'm sure that the function is being called but, for some reason, it's not changing archived to true.

The odd thing is, if I replaced "archived: true" with "read: true" it does change 'read' to true.  However, for some reason it won't change the archived attribute.

I'm sure that 'archived' is a valid attribute in the JSON API.

Any reason this would happen?  Here is the code in question:

```
function archive_email(id) {
    
    fetch('/emails/' + id, {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: JSON.stringify({
    archived: true
      })
    })
    load_mailbox("inbox");
    
     
}
```

Comment: `I'm sure that 'archived' is a valid attribute in the JSON API` - only you can see the server code that handles your request ... so, how can we help debugging your server code?

Answer (score 2):

I think is a promise problem, did you try the following code?

```
function archive_email(id) {
    fetch('/emails/' + id, {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            archived: true
        })
    }).then(() => {
        load_mailbox("inbox");
    })
}
```

Comment: Because the "fetch api" return the "promise", you need to use "then" function to wait for the response from server which would edit the data attribute to archived: true.
That means if you don't use "then function", you don't know the server whether edit the attribute or not.
You can take a look this url about how to use fetch api.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch.